# If $M$ invertible, why is there $\varepsilon>0$ s.t. $P$ is inversible if $|p_{ij}-m_{ij}|<\varepsilon$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $M=(m_{ij})$ an invertible matrix of $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. In my book it's written : there is $\varepsilon>0$ s.t. for all $P=(p_{ij})\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, $|p_{ij}-m_{ij}|<\varepsilon\implies P$ invertible.

Where does it come from ? Is it a popular assertion ? I've never see this.

Answer (score 3):

It come from the continuity of the determinant. Suppose WLOG that $\det (M)>0$. Since $P\longmapsto \det(P)$ is a continuous function from $\mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)\longrightarrow \mathbb R$, there is $\delta>0$ s.t. for all $P\in\mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ $$\|A-M\|<\delta\implies \det(P)>\frac{\det(M)}{2}>0.$$

Now, all norm of $\mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ are equivalent. So, there is $C>0$ s.t. $\max\{|p_{ij}-m_{ij}|\}\leq D\|A-M\|$. The claim follow. Set $\varepsilon=\frac{\delta}{D}$ and you'll have your result.

Comment: Oh, nice ! Could you just tell me why $\det$ is continuous on $\mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ ?

Comment: Because it is a polynomial in $n^2$ variables.

Comment: @Dog_69: Indeed, thanks a lot.

Comment: It's a pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, let $P=M+\Delta$, where $\Delta$ by assumption is entrywise bounded in magnitude by $\varepsilon$. If $P$ is singular, then $Pu=(M+\Delta)u=0$ for some unit vector $u$ and hence $\|Mu\|_2=\|\Delta u\|_2$. But this is impossible when $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently small, because the LHS is bounded away from zero (as the image of the unit sphere under the invertible $M$ is a compact set that does not contain zero) while the RHS approaches zero when $\varepsilon\to0$. Thus $P$ is invertible when $\varepsilon$ is small.